# Chrome extension Payment buy.js not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, paypal, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to sell my chrome extension. I have the manifest.json, the background.js, popup html and one more js file.

I have researched everywhere to find a way to sell this, but the only source I have found was to include this code:

```
(function() { var f=this,g=function(a,d){var c=a.split("."),b=window||f;c[0]in b||!b.execScript||b.execScript("var "+c[0]);for(var e;c.length&&(e=c.shift());)c.length||void 0===d?b=b[e]?b[e]:b[e]={}:b[e]=d};var h=function(a){var d=chrome.runtime.connect("nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda",{}),c=!1;d.onMessage.addListener(function(b){c=!0;"response"in b&&!("errorType"in b.response)?a.success&&a.success(b):a.failure&&a.failure(b)});d.onDisconnect.addListener(function(){!c&&a.failure&&a.failure({request:{},response:{errorType:"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}})});d.postMessage(a)};g("google.payments.inapp.buy",function(a){a.method="buy";h(a)});
g("google.payments.inapp.consumePurchase",function(a){a.method="consumePurchase";h(a)});g("google.payments.inapp.getPurchases",function(a){a.method="getPurchases";h(a)});g("google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails",function(a){a.method="getSkuDetails";h(a)}); })();
```

...but, they haven't told me *where* to include it.

Do I include it in a separate js file?

I have created a merchant account, and I cannot find any way to get this to sell. It is already published on the extension chrome store as a free extension, but when I put change the settings to "paid extension" on the chrome store it says it is unavailable.

Is there some secret setting I need to know about?

Comment: I guess it should be [injected as a `script` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) in DOM of the page.

Comment: Side note : Don't add thanks to posts. All information related to the question must be inline in the question and not hidden in private mails - so asking to contact by mail for mor info is not appropriate for SO posts. You are free to put contact info to your profile.

Comment: Ok, I only posted it because if anyone decided to put it off topic, they can still contact me.

Comment: @wOxxOm may you elaborate please? I am new to this

Comment: there is an official tutorial on how to monetize extensions. follow it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really useful dude, linking me to a tutorial i already read

Comment: @SamM, If you have already read such a tutorial, it was *your responsibility* to mention that, and provide a link to it, *in the question*. You are supposed to include the research and effort which you have already done *in the question* so that people trying to *help you* know where you are in whatever process is needed and can help you move forward. You can [edit] the question to provide more information about what you have done researched.

Comment: @SamM, Providing a snarky answer to someone who was attempting to *help you* is not conducive to getting assistance.